The probability of a biased coin vs a fair coin
Part 1: Person A, has a biased coin with a probability of landing heads, is $p$, whilst person B has a fair coin. They flip alternatively, where person A goes first, and keep flipping until someone gets a heads. What must the probability of person A's coin landing on heads if they both have an equal chance of winning?
Part 2:, If person B now goes first, what must the probability of person A's coin be?
Supposedly the answer for Part 1 is $p=\frac{1}{3}$, but to me that doesn't make sense.
My logic would be:
If person B has a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of winning, on the first flip, then the way for that to occur is for a $\frac{1}{p}$ event to occur and then a $\frac{1}{2}$ to occur (person A not getting heads and then person B getting heads). But this needs to be equal to person A getting heads.
Which is:
$$\frac{1}{p} \frac{1}{2} = p$$
$$\therefore p = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
If person B does not land heads on their first flip, we get the same scenario of A going first since all flips are independent. Where is the flaw in my logic?
Then similarly in part 2; in the reverse case, $p=1$ if person B flips first since person B has a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of getting heads on the first go, meaning they both have the same probability of winning since it's only dependent on person B's coin, which is 1/2...

The probability of Player A not winning is $1-p$, not $1/p$. This gives $(1-p)\frac12 =p$. This gives the answer as $1/3$.
Similarly, for part 2, we get $\frac12 p =\frac12$. This gives 1, as you showed.
